# Core Data and BOOL setup

Tags: iphone, core-data, ipad

I am working on an app that uses Core Data as its backend for managing SQLite records.  I have everything working with strings and numbers, but have just tried adding BOOL fields and can't seem to get things to work.

In the .xcdatamodel, I have added a field to my object called `isCurrentlyForSale` which is not Optional, not Transient, and not Indexed.  The attribute's type is set to Boolean with default value NO.

When I created the class files from the data model, the boilerplate code added for this property in the .h header was:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isCurrentlyForSale;
```

along with the

```
@dynamic isCurrentlyForSale;
```

in the .m implementation file.

I've always worked with booleans as simple BOOLs.  I've read that I could use NSNumber's `numberWithBool` and `boolValue` methods, but this seems like an aweful lot of extra code for something so simple.

Can the @property in the header be changed to a simple BOOL?  If so is there anything to watch out for?

Thanks
-John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple response:  No, you cannot change the `@property` declaration to return a `BOOL`.

You can write some simple wrappers, though. I'd rename the attribute to `currentlyForSale` (which means it generates `currentlyForSale` and `setCurrentlyForSale:`), and then write two wrappers:

```
- (BOOL) isCurrentlyForSale {
  return [[self currentlyForSale] boolValue];
}

- (void) setIsCurrentlyForSale:(BOOL)forSale {
  [self setCurrentlyForSale:[NSNumber numberWithBool:forSale]];
}
```

Comment: A setter nor a property should have "is" in it.  That is why `@property` has the `getter=` setting.  And yes you can have the `@property` be changed to BOOL by using the primitive accessors that are part of Core Data.

Comment: @Marcus Yes, I know that setters shouldn't have `Is` in them, but I put it in because `setCurrentlyForSale:` was already taken by CD (and I am aware of `getter=` and `setter=`.  And are you saying that you can just change the `NSNumber *` to `BOOL` in the header and it'll work?  That would *definitely* surprise me.

Answer (score 30):

While Dave DeLong's answer is close, you can actually do this without having to change the name of the property.

You **can** change the property to return a `BOOL` but you need to then write the accessor methods by hand and they are a bit different than what Dave has in his response.

First your `@property` should be defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isCurrentlyForSale) BOOL currentlyForSale;
```

Then in your implementation file, instead of declaring a `@dynamic` property, create the accessors directly.

```
- (BOOL)isCurrentlyForSale
{
  [self willAccessValueForKey:@"currentlyForSale"];
  BOOL b = [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"currentlyForSale"] boolValue];
  [self didAccessValueForKey:@"currentlyForSale"];
  return b;
}

- (void)setCurrentlyForSale:(BOOL)b
{
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"currentlyForSale"];
  [self setPrimitiveValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:b] forKey:@"currentlyForSale"];
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"currentlyForSale"];
}
```

With these accessors your object will handle the boxing for you and you can access it as a primitive value.  Also, a setter starting with `setIs` is not a great idea, hence the removal of it in the example code.

Comment: +1 ah, I get what you're saying now.  I thought you were implying that you could change the `@property` to `BOOL` and not implement custom methods.  As an aside, the setter is slightly incorrect.  The `(will|did)ChangeValueForKey:` should only be invoked if the new value is actually different (ie, you need an if statement).

Comment: The only thing I would add, is that I like to use NSString constants for the key names, it saves from having to trouble shoot typographical errors later.

`NSString *const CurrentlyForSale = @"currentlyForSale";`