# Storing an NSURL as a string in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsurl

I'm beginning to play around with Core Data and just have a question around storing something like a URL.

I've currently got it configured as a transformable which is working fine however I feel that it's probably storing excess data unnecessarily and since it can be easily represented with text I'm wondering whether I should just be storing the absolute URL as a string and instantiating an NSURL object when it's loaded (I suspect this is the case) and if so how should this be implemented?

My research so far leads me to think maybe use mogenerator and then just override the property accessors to deal with the conversion between the string and NSURL. Would just like to get a sense of how this or normally done or whether I am just making things difficult for myself by even bothering.

Cheers
Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on Monogenerator or not, I will use the second approach. Override "getters" and "setters", perform the mapping from the URL to the string with

```
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
```

and use `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` and its counterpart like

```
- (void)setYourURL:(NSURL*)newURL {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"yourURL"]; // call to notify the world you are modifying that property
    NSString* yourURLAsString = // perform the conversion here...
    [self setPrimitiveValue:yourURLAsString forKey:@"yourURL"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"yourURL"]; // call to notify the world you've modified that property
}
```

If your URL has spaces, you may also think to replace them with `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`.

Comment: I think you meant for that argument to be a URL rather then a string? If so then thats pretty much how I was thinking of doing it. The example code helps though.

Comment: @NickDancer Sorry my fault. I fixed it.

Comment: Why do you use the primitive accessors? Why not just `NSString* yourURLAsString = ...; [self setValue:yourURLAsString forKey:@"yourURL"];` ? - Alternatively, one could define a transient property with custom accessors.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, you are correct. But in this way you can centralize code in a single point and continue to work with URLs. I don't know if my approach could be wrong. What do you think?

Comment: A discussion on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850532/core-data-and-bool-setup

Comment: @flexaddicted: I did not want to criticize! I just noted that `willChangeValueForKey` + `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` + `didChangeValueForKey` is the same as `setValue:forKey:`. - Using a transient property has the small advantage that the converted URL can be cached, so that the getter function does not have to convert each time it is called.

Comment: @flexaddicted: Ah, now I understand! I did not notice that you *override* the accessor function. Please ignore my comments about `setValue` and `setPrimitiveValue`, sorry!

Comment: @MartinR No problem. Maybe, my comment *I'm ready to accept criticism* has been misunderstood. With that I mean that I'm ready to accept any advice if they can help me to know something new in Core Data and iOS in general. Thank you very much and sorry if I expressed myself in a wrong way.

Comment: @flexaddicted: No problem at all! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 10):

The answer depends somewhat on the URL actually *is*.

#### For `file` URLs

Use `NSURL`'s routines for generating bookmark data and store that instead. This makes you resilient to files moving around, and can include security-scoping for sandboxed apps.

#### For everything else

Your options are to store:

- String representation from `-absoluteString`
- Data representation from `CFURLGetBytes()`
- Data as produced by using an `NSCoder`

The last is probably only useful if you have URLs comprised of a `-baseURL` and wish to persist that knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

In *Xcode 9* and *iOS 11+* you can simply use new **URI** type for storing `URL`.