# Fetching a NSString version of NSURL from Core Data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, avfoundation

I have an `NSURL` that I'm using to create an `AVAsset`.  I then use the `AVAsset` to extract data from the media file the `NSURL` represents.  This has been working fine until I started using `Core Data`.  To make this work with `Core Data` I have to convert the `NSURL` to an `NSString` as an attribute for my `entity`.  Now when I'm fetching, I can see that I'm able to retrieve the string version of the `NSURL` and convert it back to an `NSURL`. However, when I create my `AVAsset` from the `NSURL` I'm unable to extract the data.

Storing NSURL as NSString method:

```
-(void) saveRecording:(NSMutableDictionary*) recordPackage inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*) context
{

    Recording * recording = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recording" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    recording.audioURL = [[recordPackage objectForKey:@"audioURL"] absoluteString];    
}
```

Fetching method:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) fetchWithContext: (NSManagedObjectContext*) context
{

    NSFetchRequest * request;

    if(request == nil)
    {
        request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Recording"];
        request.predicate = nil;
        request.sortDescriptors = nil;
    }

    NSError * error;

    return [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

}

viewDidLoad of tableView:

```
    NSMutableArray * testArray  = [self.managedDocument fetchWithContext:self.managedDocument.managedObjectContext];
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath of tableView:

```
Recording * recording = [self.audioTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSLog(@"THEURL %@", recording.audioURL);

NSURL * audioURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[recording.audioURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

AVAsset * transferredAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:audioURL];
[cell setAsset:transferredAsset];
```

When I `NSLog` the fetched `NSString` from `Core Data` it matches the url I had before storing.  What gives?  Am I converting between `NSString` and `NSURL` incorrectly?

I saw the following answer but I'm still kind of lost: [Storing an NSURL as a string in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908580/storing-an-nsurl-as-a-string-in-core-data)

Comment: Don't add percent escapes.